# Using Apache Click with GWT

Tags: gwt, click-framework

What is the best way to use Apache Click (http://click.apache.org/) with GWT?

The concept of "Page" with Click is what really interest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although these frameworks look the same, they are very different. Apache Click has pages concepts where you generate HTML, while GWT uses Activities/Places and generate JavaScript. These two can not be combined.